# How to compare each element of two lists in python

Tags: python, list, comparison-operators

I am looking for a Python operator similar to %in% in R. It compares all elements in a list to all elements to another list and returns a boolean array. It would do the following:

```
a=['word1','word2','word3','word4']
b=['word2','word4']
a *%in%* b
>>False True False True
```

The closest thing I have found is pd.str.contains but it is not vectorized, i.e. it only looks for one element. Hopefully somebody knows.

Answer (score 4):

List comprehension:

```
[item in b for item in a]
```

This creates a new list in a way similar to the following code:

```
newList = []
for item in a:
    newList.append(item in b)
```

where `item in b` evaluates to `True` if `item` exists in `b`, otherwise it will evaluate to `False`.

---

As mentioned in comments (thanks [Paul Rooney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1540468/paul-rooney)!), the speed of this can be improved if you make `b` into a set:

```
b_set = set(b)
result = [item in b_set for item in a]
```

This is because the lookup operation `item in b` takes consistent time if `b` is a set, while every single item has to be compared until a matching one is found if `b` is a list.

The speed improvement is not very noticeable if `b` is small, but for a list `b` containing hundreds of elements, this can be a freat improvement.

Comment: Add some explanation. The OP looks new to python

Comment: @Bazingaa Sure.

Comment: You could make the time complexity linear by making `b` a set.

Answer (score 1):

Because python isn't a primarily numerical or scientific language it doesn't come with some things that are available by default in matlab or R. That being said, almost anything you'd need from those languages is available in the numpy/scipy ecosystem. For example, numpy has an `in1d` function:

```
import numpy
a = ['word1','word2','word3','word4']
b = ['word2','word4']

print(numpy.in1d(a, b))
# [False  True False  True]
```

Comment: Related (since OP mentioned Pandas and is from R), `pd.Series(['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4']).isin(['word2', 'word4'])`. Didn't think this was worth a new answer but would be a good addition to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Using *list comprehension* we can check if the item is in the `list` of comparison and return `True` if so else `False`

```
l = [*True if i in b else False for i in a]
print(*l)
```

> ```
> False True False True
> ```

Expanded loop

```
l = []
for i in a:
    if i in b:
        l.append(True)
    else:
        l.append(False)
```